# Screen reader accessibility: How “talky” should my button be?

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

I'm trying to improve screen reader support on our webapp, but I'm struggling a bit with what the best practice is for our buttons. Our current pattern looks something like this

[image]

If I focus on the button, should the screen reader say...

...Choose file, required?

...Upload personal letter: choose file?

...Upload personal letter: choose file. Allowed filetypes: doc, docx. Required?

We're currently going for the more talky version, but our team has limited experience with screen reader users and how they're used, so a push in the right direction would be very helpful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last option is best.  Everything that is visible should be conveyed to a screen reader.  There's no need to try to make it a sentence or make it "polite" by saying "please".

I know this forum is more about design not implementation, but your code should look something like this:

```
<span id="upload">
  Upload personal letter 
  <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:#e00000">*</span>
  <span class="sr-only">, required</span>
</span>

<button id="mybutton" aria-labelledby="upload mybutton" aria-describedby="types">choose file</button>

<span id="types">allowed filetypes: doc, docx</span>
```

**Notes**

- The "Upload" text is broken up into several parts.  The '*' is hidden from screen readers (`aria-hidden="true"`) because a screen reader user doesn't need to hear *"star"*.  However, they **do** need to hear that it's required (that's what the '*' means) so the word "required" is added but is visibly hidden (`class="sr-only"`) but is read by screen readers.  [More info on the "sr-only" class is on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758598/what-is-sr-only-in-bootstrap-3).  The `<button>` element does not support `aria-required="true"` nor the `required` attribute so the above solution is a work around.
- The "required" text intentionally has a comma in front of it to force the screen reader to pause for a microsecond (just like you would when reading a sentence with a comma in it) before saying "required".
- The asterisk color is changed from full intensity red (#FF0000) to a darker red (#E00000) because [full red does not have sufficient contrast on a white background](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=FF0000&bcolor=FFFFFF).  The contrast ratio is 4:1 and [WCAG requires a minimum of 4.5:1](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-minimum).
- The `<button>` has an accessible name (`aria-labelledby`) that is composed of two elements (upload and mybutton).  That will cause the screen reader to say *"Upload personal letter, required, choose file"*.
- And finally, the button has an accessible *description* (`aria-describedby`) that announces the file types.  Some screen readers will read the description after the accessible name and others will tell you there is a description and to press a certain keyboard shortcut to hear it.  It's up to the screen reading software to decide how it wants to present `aria-describedby`.  But generally you'll hear *"Upload personal letter, required, choose file, allowed filestypes: doc, docx"*

That's the most "talky" version and is the correct thing to do.

Comment: I would personally use the text "Upload personal letter (required)". This doesn't need to be made clear somehow and somewhere for anyone.

Answer (score 0):

"Select document file to upload"

You can keep "allowed filetypes" for clarity and extra help.